# Search in Stack

Tags: java, stack

I've a Java Stack created and some custom objects added to it. These objects contains unique id as one of their field. I need to get the index of that object in stack based on the unique name. Please find the example.

```
class TestVO{

 private String name;
 private String uniqueId;
//getters and setters
}
public class TestStack{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  TestVO vo1=new TestVO();
TestVO vo2=new TestVO();
TestVO vo3=new TestVO();

vo1.setName("Test Name 1")
vo1.setId("123")

vo2.setName("Test name 2");
vo2.setId("234");

Stack<TestVO> stack=new Stack<TestVO>();
stack.add(vo1);
stack.add(vo2);

//I need to get the index of a VO from stack using it's unique ID
}

}
```

Can someone please help me to implement this?

Comment: Why do you need to use a stack?  A stack isn't appropriate for this.  Is this homework?

Comment: I need to construct a breadcrumb navigation. I thought stack is convenient for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, implement the hashCode and equals methods for the `TestVO` class:

```
class TestVO{

 private String name;
 private String uniqueId;

 public boolean hashCode() {
  if (uniqueId == null) return 0;
  return uniqueId.hashCode();
 }

 public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof TestVO) {
   TestVO other = (TestVO) o;
   return o.uniqueId.equals(uniqueId);
  }
  return false;
 }
//getters and setters
}
```

Please note that in the equals method you should add extra code to check that `o.uniqueId` is not null.

Now you can find the index of a TestVO object using its uniqueId using this code:

```
int index = stack.indexOf(vo1);
```

Comment: +1 The `instanceof` operator returns `false` on `null`, so an explicit check is unnecessary: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.2

Comment: @Stephen C's answer addresses this effectively.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `search` method for `Stack`. It will return the distance of that object from the stack top. Hopefully that's good enough. You will need to define the `equals` method - which should be pretty easy - just do a comparison on your id field.

[Java API Documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#search%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel.Could you please let me know if overriding equals method for that VO is the best way to do it? Is there any way to achieve this without modifying VO code?

Comment: I suppose if you can't change that class the best alternative would be to create a subclass and override the equals method. Then you just cast to the new subclass (I think that works, better try it for yourself!) when you're pushing onto the stack. That, or just use the new class when creating objects.

Comment: @WPS: `search()  uses `equals()`. @Daniel: +1 Consider citing a more recent link.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to base your notion of equality on the `uniqueId` field, then you should probably take steps to ensure that the field is properly initialized, and that it doesn't change once it has been initialized.

If you provide an unrestricted setter for the field, then you will get all sorts of broken behavior if some piece of code changes the field after the `TestVO` object has been inserted into a set or map.